# How to fix "The constructor Timer(int, new ActionListener(){}) is undefined" error in JAVA?

Tags: java, timer

I wanted to write the code for the timer, but I guess I wrote something wrong or didn’t write it at all.

I searched for the same problem here. Most of the answers were about a right import, but it didn’t help as my import is right, in my opinion

```
 import javax.swing.Timer;

 timer = new Timer(delay, new ActionListener()
             {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
                {
                    update();
                    repaint();  
                }
            });

ERROR MESSAGE: "The constructor Timer(int, new ActionListener(){}) is undefined."
```

I would appreciate your help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What `ActionListener` did you import?

Comment: check your import statement:  import java.awt.event.ActionListener

Comment: Thank you so much. Now I see my mistake. I used the wrong import for ActionListener. Thanks a lot for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Review the import statement as below,

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.Timer;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] arg) {

        int delay =1000;
        Timer timer = new Timer(delay , new ActionListener(){
           @Override
           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
           {
               update();
               repaint();  
           }

           private void repaint() {
             // Do repainttask          
           }

           private void update() {
              //  Do update task            
           }  

       });

    }
```